# Why warning when trying to reflection on empty argument function

Tags: java, reflection

I was trying to use reflection to call `funcA()` of a class `ClsA`. However `Eclipse Juno` is showing a warning in `TestA` class remark with `warning (A)` as shown below.

The `ClsA` is like this:

```
public class ClsA {
   String varA;

   ...
   ...

   private String funcA() {
      return varA;
   }
}
```

This is the code I use the reflection call on `funcA()`:

```
public class TestA {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClsA clsA = new ClsA();

      Class noparam[] = {};
      Method funcA;
      String retStr;

      funcA = ClsA.class.getDeclaredMethod("funcA", noparam);
      funcA.setAccessible(true);
      retStr = (String) funcA.invoke(clsA, null); // warning (A)
   }
}
```

And this is the warning I get. Basically I just don't really understand what is the message that warning trying to bring? How could I explicitly cast a `null`?

> The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to Object[] for
>   the invocation of the varargs method invoke(Object, Object...) from
>   type Method. It could alternatively be cast to Object for a varargs
>   invocation

Answer (score 3):

There can be 2 types of method invocation, one is to call with fixed argument, other is to call with variable arguments.

If you are providing just null as argument, it is not clear to java whether that method is for variable parameters or no parameter at all (as variable parameters may also accept no agrument).

So it asks to mention explicitly like (Object[])null or (Object)null, even if you don't want to provide any argument.

[Invoking Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Comment: To make my arguments to reflection less ambiguous, I just say `invoke(instance, new Object[]{/*arguments*/})`.

Comment: `(Object[])null or (Object)null` is the most interesting one, now I know how could I cast a null ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since the method signature is `(Object obj, Object... vars)` unless you declare the null cast the most forward approach is to not include any arguments.

Example from your code above:

```
retStr = (String) funcA.invoke(clsA);
```

Anytime there are VarArgs (Something...) it means 0 or more.